# How should I appear the image in the page?

Tags: php

Where should I place a the image enable to appear, and what code should be insert I mean how to put some (`'admin/savephp/images/<?php echo $rows['image']; ?>')` because this is the place where the image was place

```
<?php
    include('../connect.php');
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM candposition ORDER BY posid ASC");
    $result->bindParam(':userid', $res);
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    $dsds=$row['posid'];

    $resulta = $db->prepare("SELECT sum(votes) FROM candidates WHERE posid= :a");
    $resulta->bindParam(':a', $dsds);
    $resulta->execute();

    for($i=0; $rowa = $resulta->fetch(); $i++){
        $dsada=$rowa['sum(votes)'];
    }

    echo '<div style="margin-top: 18px;">';
    echo '<strong>'.$row['pos_name'].'&nbsp;'.'</strong><br>';

    $results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidates,users WHERE candidates.idno=users.idno AND posid= :a ORDER BY votes DESC");
    $results->bindParam(':a', $dsds);
    $results->execute();
    for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++){

    if($dsds=='Commissoner'){
        echo $rows['course'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$rows['name'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$rows['votes'];

    } else {
        echo $rows['lastname'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$rows['votes'];
    }
    $sdsd=$dsada    
?>
    <img src="../img/percent.gif"width='<?php echo(100*round($rows['votes']/($sdsd),2)); ?>'height='10'>
<?php 
    echo(100*round($rows['votes']/($sdsd),2)); 
?>
%<br>
<?php
    }
    }

?>
```

[image: here's the image]

Comment: Huh? This is not clear what you are asking...

Comment: I'm sorry, the problem is how should I put the image in the php?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this whereever you need the image

```
echo '<img src="admin/savephp/images/'.$rows['image'].'" \>';
```

Comment: thank you , it works thank you for the time god bless :)

Comment: but how to insert if I want to set a height and width for the image?

Comment: You can either use Css with the id attribute or class, that i would recommend or doing this `echo '<img src="admin/savephp/images/'.$rows['image'].'" width="200px" height="200px" />'`